# Lua HTTP PostAsync

Tags: http, lua, roblox

I am developing a script and this is what I have so far:

```
local hs = game.HttpService
local url = "http://sugargrovetemp.comli.com/NiceAdmin/currentusers.php"
local data = {
    ["name"] = player.Name,
    ["userid"] = player.UserId
}
data = hs:JSONEncode(data)
gotback = hs:PostAsync(url, data)
data = hs:JSONDecode(data)
print("successfully ammended "..player.Name..","..player.UserId.."to the php file as string!")
```

I'm new to this whole `PostAsync` thing, and I want to know if anyone can help me?

Comment: You need to explain what _doesn't_ work for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Async means Asynchronous, which means essentially that it'll wait (just as if you ran wait()) until the message has been sent before running the rest of the code.

Also, you just used JSONDecode on the data you've just encoded instead of the variable "gotback", if that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're sending it in a format your server understands (ApplicationUrlEncoded)

```
gotback = hs:PostAsync(url, data, "ApplicationUrlEncoded")
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like what you had was good, but here's something that I'd find more reliable and less of a hassle:

```
-- assert(game:GetService('HttpService').HttpEnabled == true)

local function send(tab, url)
    local HttpService = game:GetService('HttpService')
    local url = (url) and (url)
        or "http://sugargrovetemp.comli.com/NiceAdmin/currentusers.php"
    local data = HttpService:JSONEncode(tab)

    data:PostAsync(url, data, "ApplicationJson")
end
```

Now if you don't want to actually wait for the callback, then just use this version adapted for coroutines:

```
local function send(tab, url)

    local function process(tab, url)
        local HttpService = game:GetService('HttpService')
        local url = (url) and (url)
            or "http://sugargrovetemp.comli.com/NiceAdmin/currentusers.php"
        local data = HttpService:JSONEncode(tab)

        data:PostAsync(url, data, "ApplicationJson")
    end

    local newThread = coroutine.create(function()
        process(tab, url)
    end)

    coroutine.resume(newThread)
    return newThread
end
```

Hope it helps!